# What is the version of the Laravel project when it is created?

Tags: laravel

I am creating a project for Laravel in this way, what version will it be?

composer create-project laravel/laravel ProjectName

Will it be the last version of the ninth Laravel ?

Comment: It will be the latest version that's available in the laravel/laravel repository, `create-project` is basically git clone. You can read more in the [documentation for create-project](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) on how to select other versions if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

The create-project command will take the latest version unless specified otherwise.
It can be checked through CLI command and composer.

CLI: php artisan --version (must be executed on project root)
composer: the version is registered in composer.json file based in project root